# Rails 6 remote: true and multipart: true file uploads not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Can you upload files in a Rails 6 form with remote: true?

My form has remote: true and multipart:true, and works without issue when I do not upload any files.

Once I try to upload a file, I get a 406 error, and in my logs I'm seeing:

```
ActionController::UnknownFormat (AppProxy::RegistriesController£update is missing a template for this request format and variant.

request.formats: ["text/html"]
```

It seems only when I try to upload an image, I'm getting this error, otherwise my update.js.erb is running fine when other fields are saved and no files are uploaded.

Edit: It appears that the uploads are in fact saving despite the error, but I'm still only seeing this error when the form has uploads.

Comment: Not sure for Rails 6 but file upload requires a multipart request from client to server. This many times doesn't send csrf tokens in second chunk of file. Please have a look at https://github.com/JangoSteve/remotipart it should enable you sending files with remote true.

Comment: @raviture I came across that gem but it appears to be for Rails 3 and 4.

Comment: Check another repository for remotipart https://github.com/jbox-web/remotipart  it should have support for rails 6

Comment: @raviture actually I just installed remotipart and it fixed my issue!

Answer (score 0):

I assumed [remotipart](https://github.com/JangoSteve/remotipart) wasn't going to work because it explicitly says it's for Rails 3 and 4, but alas, it did work for me.

Answer (score 0):

add `gem 'remotipart'` in Gemfile

`//= require jquery.remotipart`
add this line in app/assets/javascripts/application.js (right after //= require jquery_ujs):